# In OpenMDAO's ExecComp, is shape_by_conn compatible with has_diag_partials?

Tags: derivative, openmdao

I have an `om.ExecComp` that performs a simple operation:

```
"d_sq = x**2 + y**2"
```

where `x`, `y`, and `d_sq` are always 1D `np.array`s. I'd like to be able to use this with large arrays without allocating a large dense matrix. I'd also like the length of the array to be configured based on the shape of the connections.
However, if I specify `x={"shape_by_conn": True}` rather than `x={"shape":100000}`, even if I also have `has_diag_partials=True`, it attempts to allocate a 100000^2 array. Is there a way to make these two options compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll note that you're using `ExecComp` a bit outside its design intended purpose. Thats not to say that you're something totally invalid, but generally speaking ExecComp was designed for small, cheap calculations. Passing it giant arrays is not something we test for.

That being said, I think what you want will work. When you use `shape_by_conn` in this you need to be sure to size both your inputs and outputs. I've provided an example, along with a manually defined component that does the same thing. Since your equations are pretty simple, this would be a little faster overall.

```
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om

class SparseCalc(om.ExplicitComponent): 


    def setup(self): 
        self.add_input('x', shape_by_conn=True)
        self.add_input('y', shape_by_conn=True)

        self.add_output('d_sq', shape_by_conn=True, copy_shape='x')

    def setup_partials(self): 

        # when using shape_by_conn, you need to delcare partials 
        # in this secondary method
        md = self.get_io_metadata(iotypes='input')

        # everything should be the same shape, so just need this one
        x_shape = md['x']['shape']

        row_col = np.arange(x_shape[0])
        self.declare_partials('d_sq', 'x', rows=row_col, cols=row_col)
        self.declare_partials('d_sq', 'y', rows=row_col, cols=row_col)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs): 

        outputs['d_sq'] = inputs['x']**2 + inputs['y']**2

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, J): 

        J['d_sq', 'x'] = 2*inputs['x']
        J['d_sq', 'y'] = 2*inputs['y']



if __name__ == "__main__": 

    p = om.Problem()

    # use IVC here, because you have to have something connected to 
    # in order to use shape_by_conn. Normally IVC is not needed
    ivc = p.model.add_subsystem('ivc', om.IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
    ivc.add_output('x', 3*np.ones(10))
    ivc.add_output('y', 2*np.ones(10))

    # p.model.add_subsystem('sparse_calc', SparseCalc(), promotes=['*'])

    p.model.add_subsystem('sparse_exec_calc', 
                          om.ExecComp('d_sq = x**2 + y**2', 
                                      x={'shape_by_conn':True}, 
                                      y={'shape_by_conn':True}, 
                                      d_sq={'shape_by_conn':True, 
                                            'copy_shape':'x'},
                                      has_diag_partials=True), 
                          promotes=['*'])


    p.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

    p.run_model()
```

If you still find this isn't working as expected, please feel free to [submit a bug report](https://github.com/openmdao/openmdao/issues) with a test case that shows the problem clearly (i.e. will raise the error you're seeing). In this case, the provided manual component can serve as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. It did not work and I submitted a bug report, [#1903](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/1903). I will use the full-`ExplicitComponent` workaround for now.